# Is it possible to run java servlets on android

Tags: android

I have written a servlet which I want to run on my android phone. IS this possible at all? If not whats the easiest way to incorporate this servlet onto my android phone?

In short  can I use the servlet in android?

Answer (score 2):

Servlet was made for web applications, you can best separate the logic you have in your servlet into a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and then you can make the proper execution into Android Activities components using this POJO. But, if you want just to execute the Servlet from your Android, it would be just like a URL call..then you can use the [Webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component...in this case, the Servlet is still being executed in the server, not in your device itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run jetty as an application server on android https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/. In addition have a look at this thread: [I-Jetty or Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391019/i-jetty-or-jetty)